# Product of two matrices is zero

Tags: algorithm, math

If I have two matrices, one of size M X N and and the other of size N X P, given that the product of these matrices is equal to zero, and given the values of the matrix N X P, how can I find the values of the matrix M X N?

I know that one of the possible solutions to this is a zero matrix, but I am actually looking for a non-zero matrix.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: If there is one non-zero solution, I think there will be an infinite number of other non-zero solutions.

Comment: Check out our sister site [Math.SE] for your pure math questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [Null Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29). In your case, the order is reversed. This can easily be fixed by transposing the matrices:

```
A * B = 0
B^T * A^T = 0^T
A^T = M(Null(B^T))
A = M(Null(B^T))^T
```

where `M(V)` is a matrix of any linear combination of the vectors of `V`.

**Example:**

```
    [ 4 4 8 ]
B = [ 2 7 2 ]
    [ 5 3 5 ]
    [ 7 5 4 ]

            { [  87 ] }
Null(B^T) = { [ -40 ] }
            { [-216 ] }
            { [ 116 ] }

A = [ 87  -40  -216  116 ]
    [  0    0     0    0 ]

A * B = [ 0 0 0 ]
        [ 0 0 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for `A B` to be `0`.  The trick is that if it is 0, then `A C-1 D-1 E-1  E D C B` must also be `0` for any invertible `N x N` matrices `C, D, E`.  (Or even more.)

Now take `B` and apply elementary row operations to get it into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form (this is fairly easy to do.)  Each of those operations can be represented by multiplication by an invertible matrix whose inverse is easy to calculate (it is just the reverse row operation.)

Once we have `B` in row echelon form, all possible matrices `A` are easy to find - every column with all 0s, or every time there are more than one nonzero entry in a row results in yet another independent vector that will give you a 0.  Now pick your `A` then multiply by all of the inverse row operations (be sure to do it in the right order!) to come up with your answer.